# Как в начале страницы получить общее число страниц пагинации в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Например, страница каталога, где 69 страниц.

Компонент пагинации подключается лишь в теле страницы, где и можно получить общее число страниц.

Но нужно получить их количество в хедере. Как это сделать?

Прочитал, вроде как через отложенные функции подобное реализуется, но подходящих примеров не нашел.

В шаблоне пагинации разместил код:

```
<?php $this->SetViewTarget('nav_page_count');?>
<?php $APPLICATION->AddViewContent('nav_page_count', $arResult["NavPageCount"]);?>
<?php $this->EndViewTarget();?>
```

В header.php получаю искомое:

```
$APPLICATION->ShowViewContent('nav_page_count')
```

Все хорошо, однако это число просто выводится в виде контента, а мне нужно не выводить, а работать как с переменной.

Как в виде переменной получить эти данные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хоть что-то пытались сделать? Как-то адаптировать примеры, которые нашли?

Comment: Если решать грубым методом, то в хедере сделайте запрос через API чтобы подсчитать количество элементов в инфоблоке, который нужно выводить. И разделите на количество элементов, которые могут отображаться на странице. Вот вам ваше число и без отложенных функций. Но с ними все же правильнее.

Comment: Непонятно как в виде переменной получить данные?

Comment: Заишите его в свою переменную `$var = $APPLICATION->ShowViewContent('nav_page_count')`

Comment: Это проблему не решило. Добавил скрины.

Comment: Какую проблему не решило? В переменную `$var` не попадает значение?

Comment: Я же скрин приложил. Зачем мне на фронте печатать цифры 69? Может, я как-то не так поясняю?